# javascript RegExp - get count of all html tags total characters

Tags: javascript, regex, html-parsing, html-parser

I am trying to get the count (length) of all matching HTML characters including opening (`<tag>`) and closing (`</tag>`) including any `attributes`

Consider the following HTML:

```
<div>
    <a href="#">link</a>
    <span>some text</span>
</div>
```

The HTML character length  count will be **40**
(as it counts `<div><a href="#"></a><span></span></div>`)

[This is the working regExp (on gskinner.com)](http://regexr.com?33f1m)

But when using it in javascript there is a error
See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adardesign/GL5yP/)

Comment: May I ask, why? I'm just wondering what functionality this is used for... ususally these sort of problems have a much better, non-regexp solution

Comment: You are right, I was working on a truncate plugin, and was trying to minus the HTML tag char's to get the correct max length of char's

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for the error is that your regex includes a positive lookbehind `(?<=\s)` - a feature that the Javascript implementation of regular expressions does not provide (see [Mimicking Lookbehinds in Javascript](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/mimic-lookbehind-javascript)). *(More precisely, the error is caused by the `?` following the un-escaped `(`, when not followed by `!`, `=` or `:` etc.)*

The link you provided to a working example is a Flex application written in ActionScript 3 and that does include positive lookbehinds.

You also need to add the `g` flag to the end of your regex literal to get an array of all the matches from `match`, then you can sum their lengths.

Here is a working example with the positive lookbehind removed and the `g` flag added: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GL5yP/11/).

It shows a length of `163` which looks about right, but I'll leave the counting to you.
You may need to add something in place of the lookbehind or otherwise edit the regex - I'll also leave you to work that out.

Answer (score 1):

There is a syntax error.

You have to escape your forward slashes `/` because it's also your delimiter.

```
/(<(?:[A-Za-z_:][\w:.-]*(?=\s)(?!(?:[^>"\']|"[^"]*"|\'[^\']*\')*?(?<=\s)\s*=)(?!\s*\/?>)\s+(?:".*?"|\'.*?\'|[^>]*?)+|\/?[A-Za-z_:][\w:.-]*\s*\/?)>)/
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you please fork the fiddle?

Comment: I updated the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adardesign/GL5yP/) and its still not good!

Comment: @Cyborgx37 With the lookbehind rule that is not supported by Javascript Regexp? Are you you sure?

Comment: @inhan - Ah, didn't notice that. The unescaped forward slashes caught all my attention.